# value setting issue in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am calling one HTTP get call in my application and I am setting that result to angular tree by assigning that value to on valiable.

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "/getTreeData"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
    //var uriString = JSON.parse(response);//parseReturn(response);
    console.log(response);
    var res=response.data;
    var responseRefactor1=res.replace(new RegExp("123---", 'g'), "[{");
    //.replace("/123---/gi", "[{");
    var responseRefactor2=responseRefactor1.replace(new RegExp("1234----", 'g'), "}]");
    //replace("/1234----/gi", "}]");
    console.log(responseRefactor2);
    $scope.roleList =  responseRefactor2;
}, function myError(response) {
    $scope.roleList = '{}';
});
```

But it's throwing some exception like:

> angular.js:10103 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=node%20in%20roleList&p1=string%3Ae&p2=%22e%22

But when I am assigning the result directly without using http get call , it's working fine.

```
$scope.roleList=[{
    "lebel": "Vehicle Tree",
    "children": [{
        "lebel": "Corp_Ads",
        "children": [{
            "lebel": "2016-12-Dec",
            "children": [{
                "lebel": "HEB Plus",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "PSS_BF04Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_BF04Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "PSS_18Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_18Dec16"
                }],
                "id": "HEB Plus"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Ethnic Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_14Dec16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_14Dec16_STY"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_28Dec16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_28Dec16_STY"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_12Dec16_AAN",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_12Dec16_AAN"
                }],
                "id": "Ethnic Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "San Antonio WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPS_14Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_14Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPS_21Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_21Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPS_07Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_07Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPS_28Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_28Dec16"
                }],
                "id": "San Antonio WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Joe V's",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV07Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV07Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV14Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV14Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV28Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV28Dec16"
                }],
                "id": "Joe V's"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Houston WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPH_21Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_21Dec16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPH_28Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_28Dec16"
                }],
                "id": "Houston WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Corp Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_14Dec16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_14Dec16_CSB"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_21Dec16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_21Dec16_CSB"
                }],
                "id": "Corp Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Mi Tienda",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_MT28Dec16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_MT28Dec16"
                }],
                "id": "Mi Tienda"
            }],
            "id": "2016-12-Dec"
        },
        {
            "lebel": "2016-10-Oct",
            "children": [{
                "lebel": "Primo Pick",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "MTAB__PP_05Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "MTAB__PP_05Oct16"
                }],
                "id": "Primo Pick"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "HEB Plus",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "PSS_02Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_02Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "PSS_23Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_23Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "PSS_BF23Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_BF23Oct16"
                }],
                "id": "HEB Plus"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Ethnic Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_24Oct16_AAN",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_24Oct16_AAN"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_10Oct16_AAN",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_10Oct16_AAN"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_19Oct16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_19Oct16_STY"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_26Oct16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_26Oct16_STY"
                }],
                "id": "Ethnic Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "San Antonio WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPS_26Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_26Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPS_05Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_05Oct16"

                }],
                "id": "San Antonio WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Joe V's",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV05Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV05Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV19Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV19Oct16"
                }],
                "id": "Joe V's"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Corp Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_05Oct16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_05Oct16_CSB"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_26Oct16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_26Oct16_CSB"
                }],
                "id": "Corp Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Houston WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPH_19Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_19Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPH_26Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_26Oct16"
                }],
                "id": "Houston WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Mi Tienda",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_MT26Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_MT26Oct16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_MT05Oct16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_MT05Oct16"
                }],
                "id": "Mi Tienda"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Grand Opening",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "GO_26Oct16_KW",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "GO_26Oct16_KW"
                }],
                "id": "Grand Opening"
            }],
            "id": "2016-10-Oct"
        },
        {
            "lebel": "2016-11-Nov",
            "children": [{
                "lebel": "Primo Pick",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "MTAB_PP_02Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "MTAB_PP_02Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "MTAB_PP_30Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "MTAB_PP_30Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "Primo Pick"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Black Friday",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "PSS_24Nov16_BF",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_24Nov16_BF"
                }],
                "id": "Black Friday"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "HEB Plus",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "PSS_27Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_27Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "PSS_BF27Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "PSS_BF27Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "HEB Plus"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Ethnic Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_07Nov16_AAN",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_07Nov16_AAN"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_30Nov16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_30Nov16_STY"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_23Nov16_STY",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_23Nov16_STY"
                }],
                "id": "Ethnic Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "San Antonio WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPS_09Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_09Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPS_02Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPS_02Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "San Antonio WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Joe V's",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV02Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV02Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_JV09Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_JV09Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "Joe V's"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Mi Tienda",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPP_MT02Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_MT02Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPP_MT30Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPP_MT30Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "Mi Tienda"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Corp Ads",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WO_02Nov16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_02Nov16_CSB"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WO_16Nov16_CSB",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WO_16Nov16_CSB"
                }],
                "id": "Corp Ads"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Houston WPP",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "WPPH_09Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_09Nov16"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "WPPH_02Nov16",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "WPPH_02Nov16"
                }],
                "id": "Houston WPP"
            },
            {
                "lebel": "Grand Opening",
                "children": [{
                    "lebel": "GO_09Nov16_KW",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "GO_09Nov16_KW"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "GO_30Nov16_AL",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "GO_30Nov16_AL"
                },
                {
                    "lebel": "GO_16Nov16_KW",
                    "children": "[]",
                    "id": "GO_16Nov16_KW"
                }],
                "id": "Grand Opening"
            }],
            "id": "2016-11-Nov"
        }],
        "id": "Corp_Ads"
    }],
    "id": "Vehicle Tree"
}];
```

Comment: have you tried using track by $index as suggested by the doc?

Comment: added that one, but not able to track..it's showing same error only

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$scope.roleList =  JSON.parse(responseRefactor2);` or you can also use trackby $index like below :

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
```

Comment: Ya after adding these changes, It's not throwing any error.But, it's showing angular tree in different format as compared to actual.

Comment: @SritamJagadev: At least it solved the first issue which you were facing, now you have to raise another question for that, as your current question does not have any updates... may be see how the objects are sorted...